# SQL Server : convert sub select query to join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have 2 two tables `questionpool` and `question` where `question` is a many to one of `question pool`. I have created a query using a sub select query which returns the correct random results but I need to return more than one column from the `question` table.

The intent of the query is to return a random test from the 'question' table for each 'QuizID' from the 'Question Pool' table.

```
SELECT QuestionPool.QuestionPoolID,
(
SELECT TOP (1) Question.QuestionPoolID
FROM Question
WHERE Question.GroupID = QuestionPool.QuestionPoolID
ORDER BY NEWID()
)
FROM QuestionPool
WHERE QuestionPool.QuizID = '5'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OUTER APPLY is suited to this:

```
Select *
FROM QuestionPool
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM Question
    WHERE Question.GroupID = QuestionPool.QuestionPoolID
    ORDER BY NEWID()
) x
WHERE QuestionPool.QuizID = '5'
```

Another example of OUTER APPLY use http://www.ienablemuch.com/2012/04/outer-apply-walkthrough.html

---

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8afc/1

```
create table m(i int, o varchar(10));
insert into m values
(1,'alpha'),(2,'beta'),(3,'delta');

create table x(i int, j varchar, k varchar(10));

insert into x values
(1,'a','hello'),
(1,'b','howdy'),
(2,'x','great'),
(2,'y','super'),
(3,'i','uber'),
(3,'j','neat'),
(3,'a','nice');


select m.*, '' as sep, r.*
from m
outer apply
(
  select top 1 *
  from x
  where i = m.i
  order by newid()
) r
```

Comment: Big fan of `xxx APPLY` but it makes your queries less portable.

Comment: @ta.speot.is If portability is an overriding concern on a project, yes it's better to find an alternative approach that is more portable. But tapping your database potential is the most pragmatic approach especially if it is faster than the portable ones, e.g. http://explainextended.com/2009/07/16/inner-join-vs-cross-apply/  And after all, you paid for it, might as well use the product-specific features that goes with what you bought and makes you more productive

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with SQL server, but I hope this would do:

```
Select QuestionPool.QuestionPoolID, v.QuestionPoolID, v.xxx -- etc
FROM   QuestionPool
JOIN
       (
        SELECT   TOP (1) *
        FROM     Question
        WHERE    Question.GroupID = QuestionPool.QuestionPoolID
        ORDER BY NEWID()
       ) AS v ON v.QuestionPoolID = QuestionPool.QuestionPoolID
WHERE  QuestionPool.QuizID = '5'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query appears to be bringing back an arbitrary Question.QuestionPoolId for each QuestionPool.QuestionPoolId subject to the QuizId filter.

I think the following query does this:

```
select qp.QuestionPoolId, max(q.QuestionPoolId) as any_QuestionPoolId
from Question q join
     qp.QuestionPoolId qp
     on q.GroupId = qp.QuestionPoolId
 WHERE QuestionPool.QuizID = '5' 
group by qp.QuestionPoolId
```

This returns a particular question.

The following query would allow you to get more fields:

```
select qp.QuestionPoolId, q.*
from (select q.*, row_number() over (partition by GroupId order by (select NULL)) as randrownum
      from Question q
     ) join
     (select qp.QuestionPoolId, max(QuetionPool qp
     on q.GroupId = qp.QuestionPoolId
 WHERE QuestionPool.QuizID = '5' and
       randrownum = 1
```

This uses the row_number() to arbitrarily enumerate the rows.  The "Select NULL" provides the random ordering (alternatively, you could use "order by GroupId".

Comment: Are you sure about `ORDER BY SELECT NULL` [I wasn't able to get that to work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/1017) although `ORDER BY NEWID()` worked fine

Comment: I would imagine `ORDER BY NULL` provides *undefined* ordering, but in reality it would end up being in approximate order of whichever index is being used to read the data from (nonclustered or clustered). Reading from the heap would result in ordering following the order of insertion. Parallel query plans would produce different results, but the order would *generally* be as described above.

Comment: Hmm, I've used "order by (select null)" in SQL Server 2008 R2.  As for the effect, the ordering is undefined.  In a multithreaded environment, this is even more the case.  Of course, newid() also works.  However, it seems like unnecessary work.  I'd just go by "order by groupid" in this case, since that should provide an undefined ordering.  SQL sorts are unstable, meaning that they don't preserve the original ordering in the table for identical keys.

Answer (score 0):

Common Table Expressions (CTEs) are rather handy for this type of thing...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972(v=sql.90).aspx